# Making a JSX syntax for a MockComponent and have it typed with typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, jestjs

Wondering if anybody has some good suggestions on how to crack this. Got this test helper utils I have added some types to:

```js
import { jest } from '@jest/globals'
import React from 'react'

// https://learn.reactnativeschool.com/courses/781007/lectures/14173979
export function mockComponent(moduleName: string, propOverrideFn = (props: Record<string, any>) => ({})) {
  const RealComponent = jest.requireActual(moduleName) as React.ComponentType<any>
  const CustomizedComponent = (props: Record<string, any>) => {
    return React.createElement(
      'CustomizedComponent',
      {
        ...props,
        ...propOverrideFn(props),
      },
      props.children
    )
  }
  CustomizedComponent.propTypes = RealComponent.propTypes

  return CustomizedComponent
}
```

So currently I can call it like this

```js
jest.mock('react-native/Libraries/Components/Touchable/TouchableOpacity', () => {
  return mockComponent('react-native/Libraries/Components/Touchable/TouchableOpacity', (props) => {
    return {
      onPress: props.disabled ? () => {} : props.onPress
    }
  })
})
```

But I would like to be able to call it more like

```js
jest.mock('react-native/Libraries/Components/Touchable/TouchableOpacity', () => {
  return <MockComponent 
          module='TouchableOpacity' 
          onPress={props => props.disabled ? () => {} : props.onPress}
         />
})
```

or

```js
jest.mock('react-native/Libraries/Components/Touchable/TouchableOpacity', () => {
 return <MockComponent 
          module='TouchableOpacity'
          propOverride={props => ({onPress: props.disabled ? () => {} : props.onPress, ...props})}
        />
})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at [React without JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-jsx.html), you'll see that the XML-inspired syntax (`<MockComponent />`) is just short for `React.createElement('MockComponent')`.

Right now, if you renamed `mockComponent` to `MockComponent` and tried using the angle bracket syntax, the **first** issue is that your function receives two arguments. React components are either class components that take one constructor argument (props) or functional components that take one argument (again, props). The **second** issue is that your function returns a React functional component, when it needs to return a *rendered* React element.

One way to fix this issue is to convert `mockComponent` into a React functional component and make `module` and `propOverride` props of the FC.

```
// https://learn.reactnativeschool.com/courses/781007/lectures/14173979
export function MockComponent(props) {
  const { moduleName, propOverrideFn, ...customComponentProps } = props;

  const RealComponent = jest.requireActual(moduleName) as React.ComponentType<any>
  const CustomizedComponent = (props: Record<string, any>) => {
    return React.createElement(
      'CustomizedComponent',
      {
        ...props,
        ...propOverrideFn(props),
      },
      props.children
    )
  }
  CustomizedComponent.propTypes = RealComponent.propTypes

  return <CustomizedComponent {...customComponentProps} />
}
```

The differences are subtle but important. Here I modified `MockComponent` to take in a singular `prop` argument to be compatible with `React.createElement()`. This leads to the issue of how to differentiate props that are meant for the `CustomizedComponent` and what used to be arguments for `mockComponent()`. Here, I use the JavaScript destructuring and spread operators to separate `module` and `propOverride` from the props intended from `CustomizedComponent`.

Lastly, I use the [JSX spread syntax](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html) to pass the arbitrary props intended for `CustomizedComponent` into `CustomizedComponent`, and I use angle brackets to render it (instead of returning a function).

I'll leave as an exercise for you to come up with the appropriate TypeScript definition for MockComponent's props. You can simply define it as the union of Record<string, any> and `module` and `propOverride`. However, you can get fancy and use a template definition so `MockComponent<Toolbar>` is a union of `module` and `propOverride` and `Toolbar`'s props.

Oh, and I almost forgot. Your Jest call would look like

```
jest.mock('react-native/Libraries/Components/Touchable/TouchableOpacity', () => {
    (props) => {
        return <MockComponent 
            module='TouchableOpacity' 
            onPress={props => props.disabled ? () => {} : props.onPress}
            {...props}
        />
   }
})
```

Comment: Thank you very much Vincent for the throughout explanation and code suggestion